# Java: Need help constructing a class hierarchy which contains normal and abstract classes as well as interfaces

Tags: java, class, interface, hierarchy, abstract

I must do this from the following list:
**- Bicycle
- Car
- Cycle
- JetPlane
- RoadVehicle
- Refuelable
- Train
- Transport
- Tricycle**

I figured that **transport** would be at the top of the hierarchy as an abstract class. We could then have **Cycle** extend the transport class(cycle would then be extended by **tricycle** and **bicycle**). **Refuelable** could also extend the transport class, and have **train**, **car** and **JetPlane** extend the refuelable class. Lastly, **RoadVehicle** would be an interface and be extended by car.

I hope I have explained this problem clearly, my understanding of interfaces is a little cloudy.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Names that end with "***able***" usually belong to interfaces.

Comment: And interfaces do not extend classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do the following:

```
interface Refulable...
interface RoadVehicle...
abstract class Transport...
abstract class Cycle extends Transport...
class Train extends Transport...
class Car extends Transport implements Refulable, RoadVehicle...
class JetPlane extends Transport implements Refulable...
class Bicycle extends Cycle implements RoadVehicle...
class Tricycle extends Cycle...
```

Make Refulable an interface because it can be done by various classes across your hierarchy and an adjective also suggests an interface (see Comparable, Runnable...).

I'd also make RoadVehicle an interface or you will get problems explaining what a Tricycle has to do on road.

Answer (score 0):

```
it may be help you...

package com.deb.interfaces;
public interface TransportInterfaces {

}


package com.deb.interfacesImpl;
import com.deb.interfaces.TransportInterfaces;
public abstract class TransportImpl implements TransportInterfaces{
}

package com.deb.interfacesImpl;
public class Cycle  extends TransportImpl{
}

package com.deb.interfacesImpl;
public class ByCycle  extends Cycle{
}

package com.deb.interfacesImpl;
import com.deb.interfaces.TransportInterfaces;
public interface RoadVehicle extends TransportInterfaces{
}

package com.deb.interfacesImpl;
public class Refuelable  extends TransportImpl{
}

package com.deb.interfacesImpl;
public class Car  extends Refuelable implements RoadVehicle{
}

package com.deb.interfacesImpl;
public class Train  extends Refuelable{
}

package com.deb.interfacesImpl;
public class Jet  extends Refuelable{

}
```

[Eclipse hirerachy image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/krsRi.png)